# Formatting a failing & write-locked SSD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, diskpart, secure-erase

I have a failing 4 TB 870 Evo SSD. It has lasted less than a year (thanks Samsung). I believe the SSD has entered a read-only mode because it is failing. Any disk enumeration tasks take 30 seconds minimum (and up to a few minutes) if this drive is connected, and while I can recover almost all of my files via r-studio/WinHex, it no longer works properly.

I'd like to erase it before sending it in for RMA, as it was expensive ($470). If it wasn't I'd just physically destroy it and take the loss. I could just send it in as-is but I don't trust people not to snoop or scrape it for data they can use/sell. I'm also just annoyed that all my attempts to erase it have failed and now I'm determined to figure out a way.

Methods I have tried (not in order):

- These *seem* to work but evidently are just silently failing every write (data is still readable after)

  - `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M`
  - `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=64k`
- These actually report write errors on every sector

  - `shred -nv 1 /dev/sda`
  - `badblocks`
- Other methods that have failed

  - Windows format
  - Samsung Magician Secure Erase bootable USB stick
  - Encrypting the drive
  - WinHex Wipe Securely
  - DISKPART clean all (reports I/O device error)
  - Secure Erase via `hdparm` (drive is not locked or frozen, reports bad/missing sense data)

    ```
    hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass p /dev/sda
    hdparm --user-master u --security-erase p /dev/sda
    ```

Is there anyway at all to get around this write-lock "feature" and actually erase this drive, sans opening the case which would void the warranty? I'm assuming the write-lock is at the firmware level, are there tools that can temporarily disable it?

Comment: This is not going to help you now, but a lesson for the future is: encryption.

Comment: Before you blame Samsung, note that Windows has had issues concerning damaging SSD's: https://www.techradar.com/news/windows-10-update-could-be-damaging-your-ssd , https://lifehacker.com/this-windows-10-drive-optimization-bug-could-harm-your-1844868836 , https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-tests-fix-for-bug-that-defrags-ssd-drives-too-often/

Comment: In all my reading earlier it seems that Samsung just happened to release a bad batch of SSDs Q1/Q2 2021. Though I'm sure the Win10 issue didn't help. https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/samsung-870-evo-beware-certain-batches-prone-to-failure.291504/